# What is the value of $a$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

I want to know the value of $a$ that makes $f(x)$ continuous 
$$f(x)=\frac{x+3}{x^2+ax+9}$$

Comment: to make continuous at which point? or for the entire domain?

Comment: complete your question adding more details

Comment: continuous for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ must be continuous for $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$x^2+ax+9>0$$
this restriction is fulfilled for 
$$a^2-36<0$$
because the quadratic polynomial does not have any real roots, $\textit{i.e.}$ its discriminant is strictly negative.

Answer (score 1):

We know $f(x)$ is continuous on the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$ iff the denominator is never zero. So we are looking for values of $a$ such that $x^2 + ax + 9$ has no real solutions.

We can tell how many real roots a quadratic equation $p(x) = x^2 + \alpha x + \beta$ has by looking at it's discriminant $\alpha^2 - 4\beta$. In particular, if $\alpha^2 - 4\beta < 0$, then $p$ has no real solutions.

In our case, we have $\alpha = a$ and $\beta = 9$, so our discriminant becomes $a^2 - 36 < 0$. This holds iff $-6 < a < 6$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you want $f$ continuos in $\Bbb R$ you must check the existence problems. For that case it is:

$$x^2+ax+9 \ne 0 \Rightarrow a^2-4\cdot9 <0 \Rightarrow -6<a<6 $$